# how to use the getIcon function ? (Java / Net beans IDE)

Tags: java, icons, jlabel

i have created a form application with an image that is displayed using the icon property in the label

```
jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/replacment.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(640, 220, 68, 30);
```

the main idea is when the user presses a certain button , the image would disappear like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("")));
    }
```

And it works successfully , I tried to use the getIcon function to alter the code of the program depending on the image displayed in the label , for example

```
if(jLabel2.getIcon()==""){
  do something 
}
```

but i get an error saying : incomparable types Java.swing.icon and Java.lang.string.

so is there a way to do an if statement depending on the icon displayed by the Label?

Answer (score 3):

When you want to remove the icon use `setIcon(null)` then in your if statement check if the Icon is null:

```
if (jLabel2.getIcon() == null)
```

Comparing String to Icon is wrong, as the error says you just can't do that.

Comment: thanks , that does work . 

but  is there a method to do a statement depending on 2 separate icons . we have A.jpg and B.jpg 

i mean what if the icon isn't null but indeed just another image  

what method can i use to achieve the same goal

Comment: ImageIcon's toString implementation returns description if its set you could set description with the filename and compare them or extend Imageicon and override toString so you could compare them.

Comment: Another option is to use a `JToggleButton` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6743726/418556).