# How to fit ImageIcon within JButton borders

Tags: java, swing, icons, border, jbutton

I want to color some JButtons, some other questions here showed me, that it would be easier
to paint a little image (did it with gimp) and set it as icon for the JButton.

The number and size of the buttons should be variable (they're in a grid), so I want a high res image that I can scale how i need it.

The problem now is, I don't know how to 'cut the edges' of the icon, because the buttons have rounded edges.

[image: Pic is not inside the borders of the button]

Here you can see that the image is not inside of the button border.

And here is my method in the class that extends JButton.

```
public void setYellow() {
    URL u = getClass().getResource("/img/yellow.png");
    ImageIcon i = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(u);
    //Image img = i.getImage();
    //img = img.getScaledInstance(size, size, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
    //i = new ImageIcon(img);
    setIcon(i);
}
```

**EDIT**

```
package test;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import control.Control;
import view.Field;
import view.View;

public class HelloWorldSwing {

  /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TestView.initialize();
            }
        });
    }    

}

class TestView {
private static TestView view = new TestView();
public static TestView getView() {
    return view;
}

private TestView() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3));
    int buttonSize = 40;

    frame.getContentPane().add(new MyButton(buttonSize));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new MyButton(buttonSize));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new MyButton(buttonSize));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void initialize() {
}
}

class MyButton extends JButton {

int size;
public MyButton(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
    this.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
    setBorder(LineBorder.createGrayLineBorder());
    setOpaque(true);
}

public void setYellow() {
    //URL u = getClass().getResource("/img/test.png"); // 64x64 png pic
        URL u1 = null;
    try {
        u1 = new URL("http://assets1.qypecdn.net/uploads/users/0195/7210" 
                       + "/calvin_yellow_original_thumb.jpg");         
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ImageIcon i = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(u1);
//      Image img = i.getImage();
//      img = img.getScaledInstance(size, size, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
//      i = new ImageIcon(img);
    setIcon(i);
//      setBorderPainted(false);
//      setContentAreaFilled(false); did not help
}
}

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    MyButton mb = (MyButton) e.getSource();
    mb.setYellow();
}
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here are the pictures where the lines in setYellow()

```
setBorderPainted(false);
setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

are not commented out (unfortunately there is no difference)

Before button is clicked:

[image]

After button is clicked:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I added Borders to the MyButton constructor

```
setBorder(LineBorder.createGrayLineBorder());
```

and now the icons are inside the button borders. I added pictures.

[image]

[image]

But as you can see, we don't have these rounded button edges anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743726/418556).

[image]

### Update

I do not quite get what you are trying to achieve if not this.

[image: 12 Yellow buttons w/ orange rollover icon]

I made the rollover icon to be orange so that we could easily see the size of one button, but otherwise I put 4 in a row to ensure the minimum frame width did not insert extra space between the buttons in a row.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorldSwing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TestView.getView();
            }
        });
    }    
}

class TestView {

    private static TestView view = new TestView();

    public static TestView getView() {
        return view;
    }

    private TestView() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));
        int buttonSize = 40;

        for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
            frame.getContentPane().add(new MyButton(buttonSize));
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void initialize() {
    }
}

class MyButton extends JButton {

    int size;

    public MyButton(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        this.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
        setOpaque(true);
        setYellow();
    }

    public Image getImage(int sz, Color color) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(sz,sz,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, sz, sz);

        g.dispose();
        return bi; 
    }

    public void setYellow() {
        Image img = getImage(64, Color.YELLOW).getScaledInstance(size, size, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        Image rollover = getImage(64, Color.ORANGE).getScaledInstance(size, size, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(rollover));
        setBorderPainted(false);
        setContentAreaFilled(false); 
    }
}

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        MyButton mb = (MyButton) e.getSource();
        mb.setYellow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already saw that, but it didn't help. The icon still stands out the button(s).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) *"Yeah, I already saw that"* Yeah, it might have made sense to mention what you've already tried, given we are not psychic.

Comment: My mistake, these were the only methods I tried. To mention, the button is also setOpaque.

Comment: *"To mention.."*  Stop 'mentioning' start SSCCEing.

Comment: Thanks for the broad hint, I added the SSCCE. I'm going to hold on to that practice in future questions.

Comment: Note that to be an SSCCE, we need to either hot-link to images or generate them in code.  The first code I linked was an example of hot-linking, see my update for an example of generating them in code.

Comment: I changed that and I also added a picture. I hope that helps to clarify my problem. The edges of the JButton are rounded (at least on MacOs), but when I set the IconImage, the image stands out of the button borders. I want the icon the fit in smoothly into the button.

Comment: Show me an image produced with those two code lines I suggested **not** commented out.

Comment: I added the pictures plus another approach with borders. Thanks for your effort so far.